# Async logging using Twitter Futures in Scala

Tags: scala, twitter-util

I'm using twitter util futures in my project.

I want to add logging to trace a request through the components using MDC.

I couldn't find a good way to add that for twitter futures as there is no execution context that runs the callbacks. I couldn't find a way or any library implementation to refer to.

What is the better way to do this?

Thanks,
Nag

Comment: Please add the code that you tried out.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Twitter Futures because you're using Finagle or one of its sub-projects then that provides a [Context](https://twitter.github.io/finagle/guide/Contexts.html) for making data available across Futures used in a transaction.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion https://stackoverflow.com/users/2636793/hayden-sikh . We don't use finagle, but the idea seems nice. I can use the Finagle like Context with a custom implementation of the org.slf4j.MDCAdapter to make it work.